# Is there any real downside of having a bridging document between a top collection and child collections in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore, and I have a few collection that should be wrapped together under one collection. I was wondering if there is any downside looking forward, of having the data sorterd as follows:

```
parentCollection {
    parentDocument{
        childCollection1{

        }

        childCollection21{

        }

        childCollection3{

        }

        childCollection4{

        }
    }
}
```

Meaning the `parentDocument` is only there to bridge between the collections.

Answer (score 0):

A collection is identified by a path.  It doesn't matter what that path is - it is still just a collection, and you query it the same as any other subcollection.  If a bunch of collections need to be related by some path prefix (for example, to make a security rule work uniformly for all nested subcollections), then that's fine.  You don't even need that parent document to exist at all.  In the Firebase console, the missing document ID will appear in italics, and you can still navigate through it as if it did exist.

Comment: Thank you Doug! I am a bit most about what you mean about it not having to exists at all. From what I got from the documentation and my experience, I either name a document, or Firestore would name it for me. And without a document I can create another collection, for example `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("parent").collection("child")`. So how do I achieve what you are suggesting?

Comment: You need some document id in the middle of the two collections.  Call it whatever you want.  You don't have to create it, just use it in the path.